# While sending server request api returns server error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js application and i'm doing scraping from a website to fetch data. I have deployed the node api to azure. I am fetching data of different dates from the api. The api works well when there is data on the selected date. But it returns server error when there is no data on the selected date. After returning server error it doesn't return any data when i select a different date that contains data. Why is this happening? Here's my code for now:

```js
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id?', (req, res, next) => {
  let url = 'https://scrapingwebsite/' + req.params.id
  
  let resultTable = []
  let resultTable2 = []
  let resultTable3 = []
  let fr = []
  let sc = []
  let resultTable4 = []
  let resultTable5 = []
  let resultTable6 = []
  let resultTable7 = []
  let resultTable8 = []
  let resultTable9 = []
  let mdate = []
  let mdraw = []
  request(url, (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.resultTable').each((i, el) => {
        let resultTop = $(el).find('.resultTable2').text()
        resultTable2.push(resultTop)
        
       
        let resultBottomFirst = $(el).find('.resultbottom').text()
        resultTable4.push(resultBottomFirst)
        

        let resultBottomSecond = $(el).find('.resultbottom').text()
        resultTable7.push(resultBottomSecond)
      })
      let first = resultTable2[0].toString()
      console.log(resultTable2[0])
      let date = first.slice(18, 28)
      let draw = first.slice(34, 49)
      let firstPrize = first.slice(61, 65)
      let firstP = ['1st Prize',firstPrize ]
      let secondPrize = first.slice(77, 81)
      let secondP = ['2nd Prize',secondPrize ]
      let thirdPrize = first.slice(93, 97)
      let thirdP = ['3rd Prize',thirdPrize ]
      resultTable = resultTable2[0]
      resultTable3.push(firstPrize, secondPrize, thirdPrize)
      fr.push(resultTable3)
      sc.push(firstP,secondP,thirdP)

      mdate.push(date) 
      mdraw.push(draw)

      resultTable5 = resultTable4[0]
      let middle = resultTable4[0].toString()
      let resultBottom1 = middle.match(/.{1,4}/g).slice(0,5)
      let resultBottom2 = middle.match(/.{1,4}/g).slice(5,10)
      let resultBottom3 = middle.match(/.{1,4}/g).slice(10,13)
      resultTable6.push(resultBottom1,resultBottom2,resultBottom3) 

      resultTable8 = resultTable7[0]
      let last = resultTable7[0].toString()
      let resultBottom4 = last.match(/.{1,4}/g).slice(13,18)
      let resultBottom5 = last.match(/.{1,4}/g).slice(18,23)
      resultTable9.push(resultBottom4, resultBottom5)
    }
   
      res.status(200).json({
        date: mdate,
        draw: mdraw,
        magnum: fr,
        magnum2: sc,
        special: resultTable6,
        consolation: resultTable9
      });
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: u need to handle error cases right, it will be timing out if there is no data

Comment: can you share the server error?

Comment: It just shows - There was an unexpected error in the request processing.@amirhoseinahmadi

Answer (score 0):

I guess when there is no data found your resultTable2, resultTable4, resultTable7 becomes null and toString() operation fails for that reason. That is why your api fails to return data and get stuck.

Comment: I also think that is the reason. @fayezahamed